# How to create a PowerShell graphical interface?

Tags: gui, powershell-4.0

I'm working on a project using PowerShell

I would like to know what is the best way to create a PowerShell GUI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are mainly two possible ways to create a PowerShell GUI.

Either you work with Windows Forms inside your PowerShell-Script and write the code for the GUI by yourself. Random Code Example [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/07/24/create-a-simple-graphical-interface-for-a-powershell-script/).

or you can use a Script-Editor with GUI tools for PowerShell like PowerGUI or, as I prefer, Visual Studio. Foxdeploy has a really good blog post about it: https://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/10/part-i-creating-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio-a-new-hope/

Using a GUI tool to create a PowerShell GUI will save you much time and many nerves. So that's the way to go.

Comment: you're welcome. the actual thanks belongs to foxdeploy for making this blog

Comment: your right sir! well i thanks both of you,because without i wouldn't find his blog